# How to compare inputted numbers without storing them in list

Tags: python

Note: This is not my homework. Python is not taught in my college so i am doing it my myself from MITOCW.

So far i have covered while loop, input & print

Q) Write a program that asks the to input 10 integers, and then prints the largest odd number that was entered. If no odd number was entered it should print a message to the effect

How can i compare those 10 number without storing them in some list or something else? Coz i haven't covered that as if yet.

```
print "Enter 10 numbers: "
countingnumber=10
while countingnumber<=10:
    number=raw_input():
    if number % 2 == 0:
         print "This is odd"
         countingnumber=countingnumber+1
    else:
         print "This is even. Enter the odd number again"
```

i think the program will look something like this. But this has some unknown error & How can i compare all the numbers to get the largest odd number without storing those 10 numbers in the list.

Comment: *"has some unknown error"* - unknown to us, but you have a traceback to read. You will have to store at least two numbers - the current input, and the largest odd number so far. Learn lists; they aren't that complicated.

Comment: also `raw_input()` is giving you a string, so `number % 2` isn't going to work the way you want unless you convert `number` to a number first. Something like `int(raw_input())`. You've also got odd and even backwards. 3 is odd, 3 % 2 is 1.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i am going to learn them but this question is in first chapter of the exercise. How am i going to solve this question with limited knowledge of while, if-else and input statement :(

Comment: @StackOverflow ...by storing *"two numbers - the current input, and the largest odd number so far"*, as two separate variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the correct code for that:

```
print "Enter 10 numbers: "
countingnumber=1
MAX=-1
while countingnumber<=10:
    number=int(raw_input())
    if number%2==1:
        if number>MAX:
            MAX=number
if MAX==-1:
    print "There Weren't Any Odd Numbers"
else:
    print MAX
```

here are some notes about your errors:
1- you should cast the raw input into integer using int() function and the column after calling a function is not needed and therefor a syntax error
2- your while loop only iterates once because you initial counting number is 10 and after one iteration it would be bigger than 10 and the while body will be skipped.
3-an even number is a number that has no reminder when divided by 2 but you wrote it exactly opposite.
4- you don't need to print anything in the while loop, you should either print the biggest odd number or print "There Weren't Any Odd Numbers".
5- an additional variable is needed for saving the maximum odd number which is MAX.
Last note: in the code provided above you can combine the two ifs in the while loop in to one loop using 'and' but since you said you are a beginner I wrote it that way.

Comment: sir your last if condition you did {if max = -1:} shouldn't it be {if max == -1}?

Answer (score 2):

```
print "Enter 10 numbers: "
countingNumber = 1
maxNumber = 0
while countingNumber<=10:
        number=int(raw_input())
        if (number % 2 == 0):
                countingNumber = countingNumber+1
                        if (maxNumber < number):
                                maxNumber = number
        else:
                print "This is even. Enter the odd number again"
print "The max odd number is:", maxNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

In your solution are multiple flaws.

1. A syntax error: The colon in `number=raw_input():`.
2. `raw_input` returns a string and you have to cast it to an `int`.
3. Your while loop just runs one time, because you start with `10` and compare `10 <= 10`. On the next iteration it will be `11 <= 10` and finishes.
4. Also you have mixed odd an even. `even_number % 2` gives `0` and `odd_number % 2` gives `1`.
5. To get the biggest value you only need a additional variable to store it (See `biggest_number` in my solution). Just test if this variable is smaller then the entered.
6. You ask again if the number is odd, but you should take every number and test only against odd numbers.

A working solution is:

```
print "Enter 10 numbers"

count = 0
max_numbers = 10
biggest_number = None

while count < max_numbers:
    number=int(raw_input("Enter number {0}/{1}: ".format(count + 1, max_numbers)))
    if number % 2 == 1:
        if biggest_number is None or number > biggest_number:
            biggest_number = number

    count += 1

if biggest_number is None:
    print "You don't entered a odd number"
else:
    print "The biggest odd number is {0}".format(biggest_number)
```

If you wonder what the format is doing after the string take a look in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples). In short: It replaces `{0}` with the first statement in `format`, `{1}` with the second and so on.

Answer (score 2):

you can just define a `maxnum` variable and save the max in it! also you must use `int(raw_input())` instead `raw_input()`

```
print "Enter 10 numbers: "
maxnum=0
for i in range(10):
    number=int(raw_input())
    if number%2 == 0:
        print "This is odd"
        if number>maxnum:
         maxnum=number
    else:
         print "This is even. Enter the odd number again"
print "max odd is :{0}".format(maxnum)
```

DEMO:

```
Enter 10 numbers: 
2
This is odd
4
This is odd
6
This is odd
8
This is odd
12
This is odd
14
This is odd
16
This is odd
100
This is odd
2
This is odd
4
This is odd
max odd is :100
```

Comment: `number % 2 == 0` means even

Comment: no  if you try that in python 2.7 you got this error : `not all arguments converted during string formatting
`

Comment: no, that means that number is a string. (in your test)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I do input, I like to make sure I don't leave room for human error giving me bugs.

Because I put in extra checks I break code into a lot of separate function. This also gives code the quality of being non-coupled. ie) You can reuse it in other programs!!

```
def input_number():
    while true:
        input = raw_input("Enter Value: ")
        if not input.isdigit():
            print("Please enter numbers only!")
        else:
            return int(input)
```

Designing the input function in this fashion gives the code no opportunity to crash. We can now use it in a function to get odd numbers!

```
def input_odd_number():
    while true:
        input = input_number()
        if input % 2 == 0:
            print("Please enter odd numbers only!")
        else:
            return input
```

Now we can finally move onto the main code. We know we need ten numbers so lets make a for loop. We also now we need to hold onto the largest odd number, so lets make a variable to hold that value

```
def largest_odd(count = 10): // its always nice to make variables dynamic. The default is 10, but you can change it when calling!
    max_odd = input_odd_number() // get the first odd number
    for i in range(count - 1): // we already found the first one, so we need 1 less
        new_odd = input_odd_number()
        if new_odd > max_odd:
            max_odd = new_odd
    print("The largest odd value in '{}' inputs was: {}".format(count, max_odd)
```